# how to get value From XML object in action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am new to flex development. I am trying to develop a web based application. somehow I feel comfortable. I have some queries related to xml documents.

In my webservice I perform some database operation and return some xml data in XmlDocument Object format.

I tried to parse it using below function

```
    public  function objectToXML1(obj:Object):XML {
                var qName:QName = new QName("DATA");
                var xmlDocument:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
                var simpleXMLEncoder:SimpleXMLEncoder = new SimpleXMLEncoder(xmlDocument);
                var xmlNode:XMLNode = simpleXMLEncoder.encodeValue(obj, qName, xmlDocument);
                var xml:XML = new XML(xmlDocument.toString());
                return xml;
            }
```

but I don't know how to pull data from this XML

XML FORMAT

```
<REQUEST>
<STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>
<MESSAGE>BP Retrive </MESSAGE>
<DATA>
<BOM>
<BO>
<BusinessPartners>
<row>
<CardCode/>
<CardName/>
<Phone1/>
<Phone2/>
<Cellular/>
<EmailAddress/>
</row>
</BusinessPartners>
</BO>
</BOM>
</DATA>
</REQUEST>
```

Comment: Hi Manish, I think you are trying to ENCODE an object to XML in your example, I believe what you want to do is DECODE an XML result from a web service? you can use the the SimpleXMLDecoder for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a predefined structure of the XML, you could use [FlexXB](http://code.google.com/p/flexxb/) to create an ActionScript Object of the XML. It is pretty easy, you create an ActionScript Object which looks exactly like the XML (that means it need to have the same properties) and you annotate these properties. So FlexXB will read the XML and create an ActionScript Object form it.

If you don't want to use the framework, you can do it by hand too. To read attributes, use         `xmlElement.@attributeName` for getting the name of an object use e.g. `xmlElement.name().localName`. There are some functions, but since the autocompletion doesn't work for XML elements it is a little hard to find the right functions. [Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html) is an article by Adobe which explains how to work with XML. Basicall you can just use the node names as property names. In your case you could write `xmlElement.Phone1` and so on.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I saw FlexXB this class is use to convert xml to action script object. In my case it is pure xml as string. Actually XML string is very large say around 2000 tags and I need to send this xml to web service which perform some database operations.

Comment: If I want to retrieve some data from database, there is standard component which returns me xml document. hence I used two way binding to bind xml with UI controls so that there will be only one common xml file for adding new record and for updating too. In my RESPONSE xml there is some metadata and actual data is in <DATA> tag. I just wanted to retrive the value of DATA (ie. xml) as string so that I can convert it into XML object

Comment: if I understood you correctly you just want the DATA node. you could do that by looping over the elements until you found the DATA node. something like: 

`for (var node:XML in xml.children()) 
    if (node.localName() == "DATA") // you found your node!`

I didn't test the code but it should lead you hopefully in the right direction.